# How do I redirect a url to multiple urls

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have search everywhere but couldn't find the answer

**What I want is :**
Every time a user visits `mysite.com`, I want to redirect it to another URL(different/random for each visit)

For example 
 when user `A` visits `mysite.com`, redirect `A` to `google.com` 
 when user `B` visits `mysite.com`, redirect `B` to `facebook.com` and 
 when user `C` visits `mysite.com`, redirect `C` to `youtube.com`

and reset the cycle again and continues for the other user

```
1st user -> redirects to google.com
2nd user -> redirects to facebook.com
3rd user -> redirects to youtube.com
reset cycle
4th user -> redirects to google.com
5th user -> redirects to facebook.com
and so on....
```

**Edit :** I have a simple website with html & css

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Could you please give us more info about your backend i.e?

Comment: @JavierCobos I have a simple html and css website

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, thank you

Comment: @AijazAlam You are not going to achieve this with only html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to achieve this in a plain HTML + CSS (frontend) app. Normally you would do this on the backend server, storing the count of visitors or randomizing the URL to redirect to.

But, there's something else you can do if you don't control the backend. You can still add a simple JS file/script to do the redirect if you don't mind having a first landing page (index.html) than once is loaded it redirects to wherever you want.

If you want to kind of simulate a redirect please use:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

So in your html file you can add something like this (inside the  should work):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var sites = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.site2.com'];
window.location.replace(sites[Math.floor(Math.random()*sites.length)]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work like a charm for you, but remember it will be random not sequential but you would be able to skip the backend work :).

Remember that you can add as many sites as you want to the array, just separated by coma.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me :) This is working fine. But is there any easy way to do this by sequential that would be awesome :)

Comment: Unfortunately not in front end without backend :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could do this

```
$sites = ["www.google.com","facebook.com", "youtube.com"];
if (apc_exists('app:index') !== false)
{
    $index = apc_get('app:index');
    $index++;
}
else
{
    $index = 0;
    apc_store('app:index', $index);
}
header('Location: http://'.$sites[$index%3]);
```

Comment: Hi @rashed , Thank you for the answer I am not using PHP , I am using html & css. can i still use this code?

Comment: He is not handling backend, please check my response where I offer you a pure HTML + CSS solution :)